# Why is minecraft stuck on the red loading screen?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft copy has recently been stuck on the red "Mojang" loading screen. All attempts at cleaning the disc have failed, and I have resorted to giving up. What do I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a corrupted installation from a recent update. Here is what you should do to fix it.
WARNING: THIS WILL ERASE YOUR SAVES. BACK THEM UP!

- Take out the disc and close the game. (If you have a digital copy, just close the game.)
- Go to settings - storage - Internal (Or game install area) - applications
- Go to Minecraft, hit options - Delete.
- Select Minecraft. Hit delete and confirm.
- Exit settings, go to the game library and reinstall Minecraft. (If using a disk, just reinsert it)
- Wait for it to update, and your game is now fixed!